# kubernetes ingress 502 bad gateway

Tags: kubernetes, centos, nginx-ingress, firewalld, bare-metal-server

I installed a Kubernetes Cluster on bare metal (using VMware virtual machines) with the following nodes

```
master-01   Ready    control-plane,master   5d3h   v1.21.3
master-02   Ready    control-plane,master   5d3h   v1.21.3
master-03   Ready    control-plane,master   5d3h   v1.21.3
worker-01   Ready    <none>                 5d2h   v1.21.3
worker-02   Ready    <none>                 5d2h   v1.21.3
worker-03   Ready    <none>                 5d2h   v1.21.3
```

Metallb is installed as loadbalancer for the cluster and calico as CNI

I also installed nginx-ingress-controller with helm

```
$ helm repo add nginx-stable https://helm.nginx.com/stable
$ helm repo update
$ helm install ingress-controller nginx-stable/nginx-ingress
```

I deployed a simple nginx server for testing

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx-app
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx-app
  #type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-myapp
  annotations:
    # use the shared ingress-nginx
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myapp.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

My deployments with loadbalancer types get their IP from metallb and works fine but when I add ingress although an IP is assigned I get error 502 bad gateway as shown below:

firewall is enabled but required ports are opened

```
6443/tcp 2379-2380/tcp 10250-10252/tcp 179/tcp 7946/tcp 7946/udp 8443/tcp on master nodes
10250/tcp 30000-32767/tcp 7946/tcp 7946/udp 8443/tcp 179/tcp on worker nodes
```

My services and pods works fine

```
 kubectl get svc -o wide
NAME                               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)                      AGE   SELECTOR
ingress-controller-nginx-ingress   LoadBalancer   10.101.17.180   10.1.210.100   80:31509/TCP,443:30004/TCP   33m   app=ingress-controller-nginx-ingress
kubernetes                         ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>         443/TCP                      6d    <none>
nginx-service                      ClusterIP      10.101.48.198   <none>         80/TCP                       31m   app=nginx-app
```

My ingress logs gives me error with no route to the internal IP

```
2021/07/29 07:46:24 [error] 42#42: *8 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.1.210.5, server: myapp.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.168.171.17:80/", host: "myapp.com"
10.1.210.5 - - [29/Jul/2021:07:46:24 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "curl/7.68.0" "-"
W0729 07:50:16.416830       1 warnings.go:70] networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 Ingress is deprecated in v1.19+, unavailable in v1.22+; use networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress
192.168.2.131 - - [29/Jul/2021:07:51:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36" "-"
192.168.2.131 - - [29/Jul/2021:07:51:03 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "http://10.1.210.100/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36" "-"
W0729 07:56:43.420282       1 warnings.go:70] networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 Ingress is deprecated in v1.19+, unavailable in v1.22+; use networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress
W0729 08:05:28.422594       1 warnings.go:70] networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 Ingress is deprecated in v1.19+, unavailable in v1.22+; use networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress
W0729 08:10:45.425329       1 warnings.go:70] networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 Ingress is deprecated in v1.19+, unavailable in v1.22+; use networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress
2021/07/29 08:13:59 [error] 42#42: *12 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.1.210.5, server: myapp.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.168.171.17:80/", host: "myapp.com"
10.1.210.5 - - [29/Jul/2021:08:13:59 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "curl/7.68.0" "-"
2021/07/29 08:14:09 [error] 42#42: *14 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.1.210.5, server: myapp.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.168.171.17:80/", host: "myapp.com"
10.1.210.5 - - [29/Jul/2021:08:14:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "curl/7.68.0" "-"
```

Any idea please ?

EDIT : As asked here description of services and pods

```
$ kubectl describe pod nginx-deployment-6f7d8d4d55-sncdr
Name:         nginx-deployment-6f7d8d4d55-sncdr
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         worker-01/10.1.210.63
Start Time:   Thu, 29 Jul 2021 08:43:59 +0100
Labels:       app=nginx-app
              pod-template-hash=6f7d8d4d55
Annotations:  cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 192.168.171.17/32
              cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 192.168.171.17/32
Status:       Running
IP:           192.168.171.17
IPs:
  IP:           192.168.171.17
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/nginx-deployment-6f7d8d4d55
Containers:
  nginx:
    Container ID:   docker://fc61b73f8a833ad13b8956d8ce151b221b75a58a9a2fbae928464f3b0a77cca2
    Image:          nginx
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://nginx@sha256:8f335768880da6baf72b70c701002b45f4932acae8d574dedfddaf967fc3ac90
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Thu, 29 Jul 2021 08:44:01 +0100
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-wkc48 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-wkc48:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From               Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  16m   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/nginx-deployment-6f7d8d4d55-sncdr to worker-01
  Normal  Pulling    16m   kubelet            Pulling image "nginx"
  Normal  Pulled     16m   kubelet            Successfully pulled image "nginx" in 1.51808376s
  Normal  Created    16m   kubelet            Created container nginx
  Normal  Started    16m   kubelet            Started container nginx

$ kubectl describe svc ingress-controller-nginx-ingress
Name:                     ingress-controller-nginx-ingress
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-controller
                          app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                          app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-controller-nginx-ingress
                          helm.sh/chart=nginx-ingress-0.10.0
Annotations:              meta.helm.sh/release-name: ingress-controller
                          meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
Selector:                 app=ingress-controller-nginx-ingress
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.101.17.180
IPs:                      10.101.17.180
LoadBalancer Ingress:     10.1.210.100
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 http  31509/TCP
Endpoints:                192.168.37.202:80
Port:                     https  443/TCP
TargetPort:               443/TCP
NodePort:                 https  30004/TCP
Endpoints:                192.168.37.202:443
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Local
HealthCheck NodePort:     31108
Events:
  Type    Reason        Age                    From                Message
  ----    ------        ----                   ----                -------
  Normal  IPAllocated   18m                    metallb-controller  Assigned IP "10.1.210.100"
  Normal  nodeAssigned  3m21s (x182 over 18m)  metallb-speaker     announcing from node "worker-02"

$ kubectl describe svc nginx-service
Name:              nginx-service
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=nginx-app
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.101.48.198
IPs:               10.101.48.198
Port:              <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:        80/TCP
Endpoints:         192.168.171.17:80
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>

$ kubectl exec -it ingress-controller-nginx-ingress-dd5db86dc-gqdpm -- /bin/bash
nginx@ingress-controller-nginx-ingress-dd5db86dc-gqdpm:/$ curl 192.168.171.17:80
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.171.17 port 80: No route to host
nginx@ingress-controller-nginx-ingress-dd5db86dc-gqdpm:/$ curl 192.168.171.17
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.171.17 port 80: No route to host
nginx@ingress-controller-nginx-ingress-dd5db86dc-gqdpm:/$ curl 10.101.48.198
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.101.48.198 port 80: Connection timed out
nginx@ingress-controller-nginx-ingress-dd5db86dc-gqdpm:/$ curl nginx-deployment-6f7d8d4d55-sncdr
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: nginx-deployment-6f7d8d4d55-sncdr
nginx@ingress-controller-nginx-ingress-dd5db86dc-gqdpm:/$
```

To be honest I don't understand why curl svcip doesn't work anymore; yesterday it worked.

Comment: can u post kubectl describe nginx-service if it has any endpoints  . also you can go inside the nginx controller containers and execute a curl svcip:80 and curl podid:80 from there

Comment: I edited my post with information you requested,
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The problem was a firewall issue I disabled firewalld and it works now, I thought that had to open port 8443 but it seems to be another port if anyone can tell me which one

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with a traefik ingress in k3s. I enabled masquerade in firewalld
`firewall-cmd --permanent --add-masquerade && firewall-cmd --reload`

Credit to this post for the idea: https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/issues/1646#issuecomment-881191877